# Count of two types of values in same field in MS-Access

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have this table customerDetail, in which there's a field c_type, in which "a" represents "active" and "d" represents "not-active". Now I have to find the count of both of them in same query.
I used these but no result.

```
SELECT Count(c_type) AS Active, Count(c_type) AS Not_Active  
FROM customerDetail  
WHERE c_type="a" OR c_type="d"
```

of course I know it obviously looks dirty, but I have also tried this, but this didn't worked either-

```
SELECT
    Count(customerDetail.c_type) AS Active,
    Count(customerDetail_1.c_type) AS Not_Active  
FROM customerDetail INNER JOIN customerDetail AS customerDetail_1  
ON customerDetail.Id=customerDetail_1.Id  
WHERE (customerDetail.c_type="a") AND (customerDetail_1.c_type="d")
```

But again it wasn't helpful either, so can anyone please tell me how am I supposed to know the count of both active and non-active in same query?

Comment: Catcall's answer is much simpler than the one you chose.

Comment: @Morten Of course it is..
short, simple and sweet..
but HansUp's is a little more elaborate, I needed some explanation too..
hope you don't mind ;-)

Comment: not at all... just pointing at the right way (IMHO) to solve your problem :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(IIF(c_type = "a", 1, 0)) AS Active,
  SUM(IIF(c_type = "d", 1, 0)) AS Not_Active,
FROM customerDetail
WHERE c_type IN ("a", "d")
```

That was for MS Access.

Somehow I missed the `tsql` tag when first saw this question. In Transact-SQL you can employ a CASE construct, which can be said of as a more powerful equivalent of `IIF` in Access:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE c_type WHEN 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
  SUM(CASE c_type WHEN 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Not_Active,
FROM customerDetail
WHERE c_type IN ('a', 'd')
```

Actually, in T-SQL I would use COUNT instead of SUM, like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE c_type WHEN 'a' THEN 1 END) AS Active,
  COUNT(CASE c_type WHEN 'd' THEN 1 END) AS Not_Active,
FROM customerDetail
WHERE c_type IN ('a', 'd')
```

Here `1` in each CASE expression can be replaced by anything as long as it is not NULL (NULLs are not counted). If the ELSE part is omitted, like in the query above, `ELSE NULL` is implied.

Answer (score 5):

```
select c_type, count(*)
from customer_detail
group by c_type
```

Comment: +1 Consider including a WHERE or HAVING condition: `c_type In ("a","d")`

Comment: ... but if he really wants the fields aliased as described, he'll have to do something else

Comment: Sh*t. That was really simple, alas I couldn't get the idea...
But thanks for help.

Comment: Yeah, including a HAVING condition would helpful. But I don't understand how WHERE would improve it though..

Comment: @Razort4x With that WHERE clause, you would restrict the input rows before the GROUP BY => fewer rows for the database engine to evaluate.

Comment: Aliasing the columns introduces a maintenance issue. At any time in the future, if there are more than these two values in that column, an aliasing (pivoting) query won't show all the counts. This query will always show all the counts, regardless of the number of values in the c_type column. Most of the time, if you want the OP's kind of aliasing, you're better off letting a report writer (or the equivalent) do the heavy lifting. And the report writer can supply a WHERE clause, if it's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is your requirement, "*in the same query*".

It would be easy to create separate queries.

qryActive:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Active
FROM customerDetail
WHERE c_type="a"
```

qryInactive:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Not_Active
FROM customerDetail
WHERE c_type="d"
```

If you need it all in one, you can incorporate them as subqueries.

```
SELECT a.Active, i.Not_Active
FROM
    (SELECT Count(*) AS Active
    FROM customerDetail
    WHERE c_type="a") AS a,
    (SELECT Count(*) AS Not_Active
    FROM customerDetail
    WHERE c_type="d") AS i
```

With no JOIN or WHERE condition, you will get a "cross join" (Cartesian product) of the two subqueries.  But, since each subquery produces only one row, the composite will consist of only one row.

Comment: That was a bit tricky, but was worth the result. unfortunately, you couldn't tell me this yesterday, otherwise I'd have cleared my interview...

Comment: Sorry about the timing.  :-)  I just noticed the tsql tag on your question.  We may yet see a SQL Server suggestion which is slicker than the Access query I suggested.

Comment: Naaw, It doesn't matter, btw, I am going again tomo for an interview, may be tomo turns out to be my lucky day.. ;-)

Comment: BTW, I prefer Andriy's approach.  You should accept his answer instead of mine.

Comment: @HansUp thanx man, last time I just panicked, and mind went blank. May be cause it was first interview of my life. I just hope to perform well tomo... (fingers crossed), and sure I'd be glad to buy you a beer if I got selected ;-)
btw. I am new on this site, so isn't there anything like so that I can add you as frnd or something? I looked your profile, but couldn't find any UI that says add frnd or anything related, so is there one?

Comment: @HansUp yeah I also think his approach is more shrewd, though yours is more elaborated, I am cool with you or him anyone having accepted answer, but if you insist I can change

Comment: @Razort4x I wasn't hinting you buy me a beer; I already got some!  I'm not aware of a StackOver feature like Facebook friends.  The best alternative I can think of would be to bookmark a user's profile page and re-visit it periodically to see what they've been up to. I like Andriy's suggestion best, and would make it the accepted answer if I were doing the accepting.  But if you're saying it's up to me ... OK, I insist!  :-)  Good luck tomorrow.